# Interfacing microSD with LPC1769 Board

Tags: c, interface, spi

So we're trying to store bytes (from an A/D converter) of data into a SanDisk 1Gb microSD card from a LPC1769 microcontroller board using the on-board SPI protocol. I know how all that stuff works, but I have no idea how to start working with the microSD card--I've seen various references to CMD0 and what not, but I don't know where to find this library or how to properly incorporate it into the C compiler for the board.

All I need is to figure out how to start the connection properly and then how to read and write data into the card at designated blocks. 
`void write(int data, int block)
int read(int block)` << if there is a way to do this simply with a library of pre-defined microSD functions, that would be AWESOME

Comment: You'd probably get a better response at http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

FatFS is a simple FAT filesystem that has been ported to many microcontrollers (perhaps it's already available for yours) that also provides the low level writing to the SD card (and you can use that as a reference for your working.. It lets you write actual files to the SD card that you can then put on a computer and read/write. This ends up working very nicely.

```
http://bikealive.nl/fatfs.html
```

There is also a nice App Note from TI that has some basic API to do this:

```
http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?literatureNumber=slaa281b&fileType=pdf
```

Although it's for the MSP430, it can clearly show you what kind of register accesses you need to write the bytes yourself and you can implement the equivalent thing.

Finally, Olimex have boards with similar microcontrollers and SD cards, and you can see what they do:

```
https://www.olimex.com/Products/ARM/NXP/LPC1766-STK/
```

I found more information specifically for your microcontroller (though the suggestions above work well as well):

Two app notes from NXP on doing what you're asking for:

```
AN10916 - "FAT library EFSL and FatFs port on NXP LPC1700"
AN11070 - "Accessing SDC/MMC card using SPI/SSP on LPC1700".
```

With this you should be all set.